# format date in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, formatting

How can I format a date as `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yy` ?

Like in VB `format("dd/mm/yy",now)`

How can I do this in C#?

Answer (score 48):

It's almost the same, simply use the `DateTime.ToString()` method, e.g:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
```

Or:

```
DateTime dt = GetDate(); // GetDate() returns some date
dt.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
```

In addition, you might want to consider using one of the predefined date/time formats, e.g:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("g");
// returns "02/01/2009 9:07 PM" for en-US
// or "01.02.2009 21:07" for de-CH
```

These ensure that the format will be correct, independent of the current locale settings.

Check the following MSDN pages for more information

- [DateTime.ToString() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)
- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

---

Some additional, related information:

If you want to display a date in a specific locale / culture, then there is an overload of the `ToString()` method that takes an `IFormatProvider`:

```
DateTime dt = GetDate();
dt.ToString("g", new CultureInfo("en-US")); // returns "5/26/2009 10:39 PM"
dt.ToString("g", new CultureInfo("de-CH")); // returns "26.05.2009 22:39"
```

Or alternatively, you can set the `CultureInfo` of the current thread prior to formatting a date:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
dt.ToString("g"); // returns "5/26/2009 10:39 PM"

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-CH");
dt.ToString("g"); // returns "26.05.2009 22:39"
```

Comment: I encourage you to follow Martin's advice and go with the predefined codes, which are culture aware. You might not need it now but in the future it could make things easier.

Answer (score 9):

```
string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)
```

Look up "format strings" on MSDN to see all formatting options.

Use `yy`, `yyyy`, `M`, `MM`, `MMM`, `MMMM`, `d`, `dd`, `ddd`, `dddd` for the date component

Use `h`, `hh`, `H`, `HH`, `m`, `mm`, `s`, `ss` for the time-of-day component

Comment: Here is the MSDN Link. Might helps others. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

In you can also write

```
DateTime aDate = new DateTime(); 
string s = aDate.ToShortDateString();
```

for a short notation

or

```
DateTime aDate = new DateTime(); 
string s = aDate.ToLongDateString();
```

for a long notation like "Sunday, Febuary 1, 2009".

Or take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) for the possibities of .ToString("???");

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DateTime.Now); // 01/31/2009
String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now); // 31/01/2009
String.Format("{dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now); // 31/01/2009
```

Comment: This example will in turn call Date.ToString(string format), as shown below in Martin's answer.  That is a simpler, more direct way, than going through String.Format.

Comment: yes, you are right, Martin's answer is the direct one, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Better yet, use just

```
DateTime.Now.ToString()
```

or

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

to use the format the user prefers.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.  What I needed to do was add a reference at the top of the class and change the CultureInfo of the thread that is currently executing.

```
using System.Threading;

string cultureName = "fr-CA";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);

DateTime theDate = new DateTime(2015, 11, 06);
theDate.ToString("g");
Console.WriteLine(theDate);
```

All you have to do is change the culture name, for example:
    "en-US" = United States
    "fr-FR" = French-speaking France
    "fr-CA" = French-speaking Canada
    etc...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is simple as you can convert to and from any format without any confusion

```
 DateTime.ParseExact(txt.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```