# Convert dd-mm-yyyy into mm/dd/yyyyy in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert date DD-MM-YYYY into default format of date time "MM/DD/YYYY" in C#.

is there string format which helps me to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [format date in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501460/format-date-in-c)

Comment: @nCdy: Replacing '-' with '/' will give him dd/mm/yyyy, not mm/dd/yyyyy as he wants. That is his trouble...

Comment: @phresnel ah sorry I failed to attend it.

Answer (score 4):

```
(DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvarientCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

(Not assuming any defaults – "mm/dd/yyyy" is *not* the default date format for most people.)

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
DateTime dt = GetDate(DateStringToConvert); 
dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: There is no GetDate(string) API in the C# System package. What method are you attempting to invoke?

Comment: DateTime.Parse(string) would be the closest match to the "GetDate" method, I'm guessing. In this case, I would recommend the TryParse() method though, just to protect against malformed input.

Answer (score -1):

```
string oldstr = "03/12/2011";   
string strDate = DateTime.ParseExact(oldstr, "dd/MM/yyyy",null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(strDate);
```

Comment: I tried this with date string: "6/1/2014" and it gives a FormatException

Comment: Okay it was my mistake... you have to use "d/M/yyyy" for the given format.