# Convert date time format from dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert dd-mm-yyyy into mm/dd/yyyyy in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772407/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-into-mm-dd-yyyyy-in-c)

I want to Convert Date time format from `dd/MM/yyyy` to `MM/dd/yyyy` in C#

Is there any suggestion how to do that?

Comment: duplicate, I've just seen this question 3 mins ago

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
string oldstr = "03/12/2011";   
string strDate = DateTime.ParseExact(oldstr, "dd/MM/yyyy",null).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(strDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTimeFormatInfo usDtfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat; //--MM/dd/yyyy
DateTimeFormatInfo ukDtfi = new CultureInfo("en-GB", false).DateTimeFormat; //--dd/MM/yyyy
DateTime result = Convert.ToDateTime("07/21/2011", usDtfi); //or: ("21/07/2011", ukDtfi)
```

Then you have a DateTime Object (result) and do whatever you want like:

```
string str = result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string DateString  = "22/04/2011";
DateTime date = new DateTime();
date = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "dd/MM/yyyy");
string NewDateString = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```