# C# date AddDays output

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following code:

```
string date = "13.04.2012";
string date2 = (DateTime.Parse(date).AddDays(1)).ToString();
```

This is working correctly without a problem but after the `DateTime.Parse` function the variable date2 is '14.04.2012 00:00:00' but i would like to have only the date '14.04.2012' without the timestamp.

I thought about using the substring function  like this:

```
string sub = date2.Substring(0, 10);
```

That would work like this but isn't there a better way to get that result?

Comment: There is already one link in stackoverflow itself, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501460/format-date-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
string date = "13.04.2012";
string date2 = (DateTime.Parse(date).AddDays(1)).ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Parse` returns a `DateTime` value, which is not really a string so it's wrong to say that it has the value `'14.04.2012 00:00:00'`.

What you need to do here is add a format parameter to the `ToString` call, or use one of the convenience formatting methods.

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime.ToString(string format)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try [DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property. May be it will be correct for this.  See the below code part

```
DateTime dateOnly = date1.Date;
```

and out put will be

//  6/1/2008

EDIT:

or simply you can try

```
DateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after formatting

```
System.DateTime now = System.DateTime.Now;
System.DateTime newDate = now.AddDays(36);
System.Console.WriteLine("{0:dd.mm.yyyy}", newDate);
```