# Format Date: Start with YEAR:: 2012/03/20 10:49:18 AM

Tags: c#, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [format date in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501460/format-date-in-c-sharp)

C# How do we format date like so,

I want the date to start with the year/month/date, etc

Comment: StackOverflow has a "related questions" sidebar at the right. The very first one answers your question. Did you try to search before asking?

Comment: before ask please try to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")