# Retrieve Data from DataGridview to textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have created a Windows Application form in **C#** which has a **datagridview control** which name is `datagridview1` and three text box which named `txtTDate`, `txtTaka`. i want to display the **datagridview records** to the text box when i select a row of datagridview. I successfully do that. But Problem is When i select a row in my datagridview textbox `Tdate` shows the date as **dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS** Like `25/06/2018 00:00:00` Format. I want to the text box only date like **25/06/2018**. How can i do that. Please anyone help. N.B:  My database `TDate` field is `DateTime`.

I use the folling code to retrieve data to text box txtTDate and txtTaka:

```
TDate.text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[TDate].Value.ToString();
Taka.text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[Taka].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [format date in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501460/format-date-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TDate.text = ((DateTime)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[TDate].Value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
Taka.text = ((DateTime)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[Taka].Value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Documentation on how to format `DateTime` can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: @MithilaDas Fixed